# parsing the xml file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing, data-analysis, bioinformatics

So, I'm trying to extract information from this xml --

```
<bdb:getTargetByCompoundResponse xmlns:bdb="http://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd">
   <bdb:smile>C[C@H]1[C@H](C)CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@](C)(C(=O)O)[C@@H]5CC[C@]43C)[C@H]12</bdb:smile>
   <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1 AuxInfo=1/1/N:4,1,8,19,12,33,25,5,30,21,6,20,31,9,10,14,3,2,13,15,29,22,34,17,26,7,18,11,32,24,16,23,27,28/E:(33,34)/it:im/rA:34CC.oC.eCCCC.oCCCC.oCCCCOC.eC.eCCCC.oOC.oCCOOC.eCCC.eCC.e/rB:s1;s2;s3;s3;s5;s6;s7;s7;s9;s10;s11;s11;d-13;s14;d15;s15;s17;s18;s18;s20;s21;s22;s22;s24;s24;d26;s26;s18s24;s29;s30;s11s17s31;s32;s2s7s13;/rC:2.8737,-5.8026,0;2.1037,-7.1363,0;.5637,-7.1363,0;-.2063,-5.8026,0;-.2063,-8.47,0;.5637,-9.8037,0;2.1037,-9.8037,0;1.3337,-11.1374,0;2.8737,-11.1374,0;4.4137,-11.1374,0;5.1837,-9.8037,0;5.9537,-11.1374,0;4.4137,-8.47,0;5.1837,-7.1363,0;6.7237,-7.1363,0;7.4937,-5.8026,0;7.4937,-8.47,0;9.0337,-8.47,0;8.2637,-7.1363,0;9.8037,-7.1363,0;11.3437,-7.1363,0;12.1137,-8.47,0;13.6537,-8.47,0;11.3437,-9.8037,0;11.0763,-11.3203,0;12.7908,-10.3304,0;13.9705,-9.3405,0;13.0582,-11.847,0;9.8037,-9.8037,0;9.0337,-11.1374,0;7.4937,-11.1374,0;6.7237,-9.8037,0;6.8847,-11.3352,0;2.8737,-8.47,0;</bdb:inchi>
   <bdb:hit>7</bdb:hit>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Polyunsaturated fatty acid 5-lipoxygenase</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>3000</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Prolyl endopeptidase</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>36320</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Prostaglandin E synthase</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>3000</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Ovis aries (Sheep)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>&gt;40000</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>&gt;40000</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 1</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>8040</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
   <bdb:affinities>
      <bdb:monomerid>50241261</bdb:monomerid>
      <bdb:inhibitor>BDBM50241261</bdb:inhibitor>
      <bdb:target>Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 2</bdb:target>
      <bdb:species>Homo sapiens (Human)</bdb:species>
      <bdb:affinity_type>IC50</bdb:affinity_type>
      <bdb:affinity>9450</bdb:affinity>
      <bdb:smiles>C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@@](C)([C@@H]5CC[C@@]34C)C(O)=O)[C@@H]2[C@H]1C</bdb:smiles>
      <bdb:inchi>InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)19(23(26)18(17)2)16-20(31)24-27(4)12-10-22(32)30(7,25(33)34)21(27)9-13-29(24,28)6/h16-18,21-24,32H,8-15H2,1-7H3,(H,33,34)/t17-,18+,21-,22-,23+,24-,26-,27+,28-,29-,30-/m1/s1</bdb:inchi>
      <bdb:tanimoto>1.00000</bdb:tanimoto>
   </bdb:affinities>
</bdb:getTargetByCompoundResponse>
```

But I'm getting the following error-

```
xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.
```

I tried this code

```
smile = 'C[C@H]1[C@H](C)CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C@@]5(C)CC[C@@H](O)[C@](C)(C(=O)O)[C@@H]5CC[C@]43C)[C@H]12'

api_binding = requests.get(f'https://bindingdb.org/axis2/services/BDBService/getTargetByCompound?smiles={smile}&cutoff=1')
           
df = pd.read_xml(api_binding.text, xpath = ".//bdb", namespaces = {"bdb":"https://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd"})
result = df.loc[df["species"] == "Homo sapiens (Human)", "target"]
```

Comment: The only problem with what you have is that the xpath you're querying will try to match nodes whose tags *match* `.//bdb`. You just need to add a `*` to the end of the xpath you have, to tell it to look for an element that *starts* with `bdb`.

Comment: In fact, if you use `xpath="./bdb:affinities"`, you'll get exactly the result you want, without having to do any cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `xpath`, you'll read it in almost as expected. We know from the output that there should be 7 rows (i.e. `<bdb:hit>` shows 7). The first three tags seem to contain only some metadata about what it returned:

```
<bdb:smile>
<bdb:inchi>
<bdb:hit>
```

These make up rows 0-2 of the dataframe.
Your actual data starts on row 3, or wherever we see the `<bdb:affinities>` tag. Based on this pattern, we can keep only the data where `target` is not missing. You can choose any other column where you know there will always be data, but in this case, we're going to stick with `target`.

```
df = pd.read_xml(api_binding.text, namespaces = {"bdb":"https://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd"}).dropna(subset='target')

result = df.loc[df["species"] == "Homo sapiens (Human)", "target"]
```

Output:

```
3           Polyunsaturated fatty acid 5-lipoxygenase
4                                Prolyl endopeptidase
5                            Prostaglandin E synthase
7                        Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2
8    Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 1
9    Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 2
```

Comment: Even better would be to use `xpath=".//bdb:affinities"`, then you'll get one row per entry, and won't have to mess around with dropping rows to get to what you actually want

Comment: When I tried that, I received `xpath does not return any nodes`

Answer (score 0):

you can build the data frame for all the attributes, and then can the result. for example:

```
df = pd.read_xml(str_xml, xpath = ".//bdb:*", namespaces = {"bdb":"http://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd"})
result = df.loc[df["species"] == "Homo sapiens (Human)", "target"]
result
```

result would be:

```
3     Polyunsaturated fatty acid 5-lipoxygenase
7                                          None
13                         Prolyl endopeptidase
17                                         None
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct output. The result should contain all of the `target`s with the exception of the sheep one in row 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on here that I think the other answers missed, so I will try to give a complete overview and explanation.

In your sample of the the code you've tried, you are querying `xpath=".//bdb"`, which will look for any element beneath the root node with a tag of `"bdb"`. There are no such elements (whose tag is *just* `bdb`), so you get `ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes`. [simpleApp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75477768/4450498) correctly identifies this issue, and suggests adding an asterisk (i.e. `xpath=".//bdb:*"`) to tell `xpath` to look for any elements whose tag *starts* with `bdb:`. However, this returns *all* of the various nested elements in the XML, since in your case *everything* is prefixed with `bdb:`, so we lose the structural information contained in the hierarchy of the XML content, leading to a mess of a DataFrame.

[Stu Sztukowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75477458/4450498) suggests dropping the `xpath` kwarg completely, which will make pandas more or less do what you want, except then you get unwanted rows resulting from the `<bdb:smile/>`, `<bdb:inchi/>`, and `<bdb:hit/>` elements at the top that you have to clean up yourself after you create the DataFrame.

Also, you need to use `http` in your `namespaces` dictionary, not `https`, since the namespace mapping for `bdb` (shown in first line/root of your XML content) is `http://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd`, with no `s`.

A clean solution that will get you exactly the DataFrame that you want is

```py
df = pd.read_xml(api_binding.text, xpath = "./bdb:affinities",
                 namespaces = {"bdb": "http://ws.bindingdb.org/xsd"})
result = df.loc[df["species"] == "Homo sapiens (Human)", "target"]
```

You can use either `xpath = "./bdb:affinities"` or `xpath = ".//bdb:affinities"` (single or double slash) since in this case all of the `bdb:affinities` elements are right below the root anyway, so the two syntaxes do the same thing.

This solution yields a `df` that looks like:

```
   monomerid     inhibitor                                            target               species affinity_type affinity                                             smiles                                              inchi  tanimoto
0   50241261  BDBM50241261         Polyunsaturated fatty acid 5-lipoxygenase  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50     3000  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
1   50241261  BDBM50241261                              Prolyl endopeptidase  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50    36320  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
2   50241261  BDBM50241261                          Prostaglandin E synthase  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50     3000  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
3   50241261  BDBM50241261                      Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1    Ovis aries (Sheep)          IC50   >40000  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
4   50241261  BDBM50241261                      Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50   >40000  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
5   50241261  BDBM50241261  Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 1  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50     8040  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
6   50241261  BDBM50241261  Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 2  Homo sapiens (Human)          IC50     9450  C[C@@H]1CC[C@]2(C)CC[C@]3(C)C(=CC(=O)[C@@H]4[C...  InChI=1S/C30H46O4/c1-17-8-11-26(3)14-15-28(5)1...       1.0
```

And a `result` that looks like:

```
0           Polyunsaturated fatty acid 5-lipoxygenase
1                                Prolyl endopeptidase
2                            Prostaglandin E synthase
4                        Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2
5    Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 1
6    Tyrosine-protein phosphatase non-receptor type 2
Name: target, dtype: object
```